# How to get the create time and user name with gitlab api

Tags: gitlab

**How to get the create time and user name about a branch with gitlab api.**

Comment: Please include some code you have tried already, this isn't a code-writing service but a Q&A site.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible.

The [branches](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/branches.html) part of the API enables you to [list all branches](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/branches.html#list-repository-branches) of a repository or retrieve information about a [specific branch](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/branches.html#get-single-repository-branch) but as the links suggest, there's no info there about when the branch was created nor about who created it. There is information about the commit the branch points to though.